# const void** const - What is the meaning of this?

Tags: c

I found some C code for a microcontroller with this instruction

```
const void** const MyVariable
```

What is the difference between `const void** const` and `const void**`? What is the advantage and when do I use it?

Comment: @Xatenev the problem is that that's tagged with C++ too :/

Comment: Read it back wards. const pointer to pointer to const void. Meaning read-only pointer to (read/writeable) pointer to read-only data of unknown (void) type.

Comment: @Xatenev: Thank you. I doesn´t find it, but this link was helpful.